# Removing sublimetext installation

Tags: removing

I followed this link

http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/

To install sublime-text 2 and i followed the steps hoping it would work and it does. Except that now whenever i open sublime. It has a default.list, sublime.desktop file that always opens with it. Then when i try to register with my license it works, but when i re-open the text editor its once again unregistered.

I think installing it how i did must of broken sublime-text altogether and i have no idea how to reverse the effects. I was hoping someone here could help me out.

Also installed it through the sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer but it turns out after doing what i did in the techno install tutorial it busted the whole thing.

i should also mention that i tried to remove these files myself using sudo rm or sudo rm -rf but they seem to be already deleted. Yet it still says they exist even though when i try to remove them now it says files could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did this:

```
sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/
```

then

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/Sublime\ Text\
```

will remove the software. If you want to make sure go to /opt and do an `ls` and then remove the directory will all its contents.

There are some residual files that you can remove with:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

And you need to redo the changes to defaults.list. So do a `sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and replace all references to `sublime.desktop` to `gedit.desktop`. Or restore a backup you made.